# Как в nginx определить, что запрос выполняется через ssi include?

Tags: nginx, ssi

Как в nginx определить, что запрос выполняется через ssi include?
пример конфигурационного файла nginx:

```
server {

    ...

    ssi on;

    location ~* \.php$ {

        ...

        fastcgi_param REQUEST_SSI <здесь я присвою значение 1, если запрос выполняется через ssi include>
    }
}
```

HTML:
`<!--#include virtual="/header.php"-->`

Answer (score 1):

из [документации](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html):

> Модуль ngx_http_ssi_module — это фильтр, обрабатывающий команды SSI (Server Side Includes) в проходящих через него ответах.

поддержку *ssi* ([server side includes](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSI_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))) вы **уже** включили выше. вернётся ответ от бэкенда — *nginx* пропустит его через фильтр перед отдачей «наверх».

если вам надо бэкенд оповестить о том, что *nginx* будет выполнять обработку команд *ssi* — оповещайте. единичку какой-нибудь переменной присвойте, например. главное — чтоб бэкенд это понял.

---

а для различения *include virtual* можно добавить необходимый параметр в *url*. например:

```
<!--#include virtual="header.php?ssi=on"-->
```

Comment: Смотрите, после того как пришел ответ на основной запрос от бэкенда, nginx снова отправит запрос на бэкенд /header.php согласно инструкции, который пришел в ответе  
`<!--#include virtual="header.php"-->`. Так вот именно в этом запросе и нужно отправить бэкенду флаг. Вот как это сделать?

Comment: @ilmirabdulmanov, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Да) Я пока с параметром и делаю, но этот параметр всюду тащить не хочется. Да и не надежно это. Его (параметр) можно забыть по ошибке, в таком случае получим бесконечную рекурсию и запрос уходит сам в себя. А вот если бы на бэкенде получить типа $_SERVER['MY_FASTSGI_PARAM_SSI_ON'], то это сразу решает мою проблему. Я в бэкенде, получив такой флаг просто направляю request на другой роут, который предназначен обрабатывать эти запросы. Вот гуглю уже третий час ничего пока нет :(

Comment: @ilmirabdulmanov, искать надо не в «гугле», а в исходниках программы. впрочем, я уверен, что *подобной* **недокументированной** возможности просто нет.

Comment: @ilmirabdulmanov, можете сами написать. вы же программист, а программа — вовсе не проприетарная.

Comment: тоже вариант. Но буду искать стандартное решение.